# Using Raycast approach to detect if player is grounded using ThreeJs and CannonJs

Tags: three.js, raycasting, cannon.js

I am currently trying to implement FPS controls And need to detect whether the player is on the ground or flying(or is jumping). So I learned that the Raycaster method from ThreeJs can be used for detecting this.
But how do I implement this approach?

My trial:

```
let DOWN_DIRECTION = new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0);
this._rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster(this._player._mesh.position, DOWN_DIRECTION, 0, 10);
this._rayCaster.set(this._player._mesh.position, DOWN_DIRECTION);
const intersect = this._rayCaster.intersectObjects(this._player._scene.children, true);
```

After executing the above snippet, I consoled the intersect value and it returned an empty array.

Original Output: []  empty array

Expected Output: Ground (Plane mesh)

Model Used: Plane for ground, Cuboid for player.

Am I missing something in the code snippet for it to work?

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it. I didn't understand what you want.

Comment: I suggest you use the following official `three.js` example for orientation: https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock. It uses the above approach to detect whether the player stands on an object or not. Besides, it's not sufficient to investigate the issue with your shared code snippet. Please share a live example instead. Something like https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/